# How do I check if a Checkbutton is checked?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have created a list of 20 check buttons for my last application using Tkinter, but I can't figure out the way to check if a `Checkbutton` is or not *checked*.

How do I check if a `Checkbutton` is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Making Menu options with Checkbutton in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929355/making-menu-options-with-checkbutton-in-tkinter-python)

For each of the menu item, you need to create and associate a `tk.BooleanVar()` that *matches the status of the checkbox*.

Since you have a lot of check buttons, you might want to create a list or dictionary to store these `BooleanVars` and associate each of them with its own `Checkbutton`.