# Show checkmark in Tkinter Menu or OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

Is it possible to show a checkmark by the currently selected option in an OptionMenu or Menu in Tkinter?

Here's my code for displaying an OptionMenu:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set('USER') # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, 'USER', 'SYSTEM')
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot showing there are no checkmarks.]

In OS X, a drop down box like this would normally have a checkmark next to the currently selected option. Does anyone know why it's missing or how to add it?

(Also, the icon on the right of the box is odd. Normally a box like this has two arrows stacked on top of each other - top pointing up and bottom pointing down. Anyone know why it's just a down arrow?)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29019760/7432. Why don't  you see if that answers your question.

Comment: Have you tried using `ttk.OptionMenu` instead?

Comment: @Jkdc - That fixes the issue on Windows, but not on OS X. It does fix the arrow icon on the right side though (double arrow instead of single), so I'll stick with it.